# Create multi dimensional array from one-to-many mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have three mysql tables: `clients`, `cars` and `insurance`. Each client can have multiple cars and each car cand have multiple insurance policies. Here's my query and a link to sqlfiddle:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.id AS car_id, b.license_number, b.brand, b.model,
  c.id AS insurance_id, c.insurance_company, c.start_date, c.end_date, c.price
FROM clients a
LEFT JOIN cars b ON a.id = b.client_id
LEFT JOIN insurance c ON b.id = c.car_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/773a5/1

So for two clients where the first client has two cars and three insurance policies and the second one has no car and no insurance, the query will return 4 rows.

What I can't figure out is how to loop this query in order to return the following structure, while avoiding duplicate client entries.

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [id] => 1
      [first_name] => John
      [last_name] => Smith
      [cars] => Array
        (
          [id] => 1
          [license_number] => 'plate1'
          [brand] => 'BMW'
          [model] => 'E35'
          [insurance] => Array
            (
              [id] => 1
              [start_date] => '2015-02-10'
              [end_date] => '2016-02-10'
              [price] => '100'
            )

            (
              [id] => 2
              [start_date] => '2014-02-10'
              [end_date] => '2015-02-10'
              [price] => '50'
            )
        )

        (
          [id] => 2
          [license_number] => 'plate2'
          [brand] => 'VW'
          [model] => 'Golf'
          [insurance] => Array
            (
              [id] => 3
              [start_date] => '2015-02-10'
              [end_date] => '2016-02-10'
              [price] => '100'
            )
        )
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [id] => 1
      [first_name] => John
      [last_name] => Smith
      [cars] => NULL
    )
)
```

Comment: People ask this kind of question a lot. But its really simple: loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy. It is about using an assoc arrays. You could use id, car_id and insurance_id as array keys.

So assuming you got the result as fetched assoc rows stored in $rows variable. The simple loop will be:

```
$result = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $id    = $row['ID'];
    $carId = $row['CAR_ID'];
    $insId = $row['INSURANCE_ID'];

    $result[$id]['first_name'] = $row['FIRST_NAME'];
    $result[$id]['last_name']  = $row['LAST_NAME'];

    if(!isset($result[$id]['cars'])) {
        $result[$id]['cars'] = array();
    }

    if($carId && !isset($result[$id]['cars'][$carId])) {
        $car = array(
            'id'             => $row['CAR_ID'],
            'license_number' => $row['LICENSE_NUMBER'],
            'brand'          => $row['BRAND'],
            'model'          => $row['MODEL'],
            'insurance'      => array()
        );
        $result[$id]['cars'][$carId] = $car;
    }

    if($insId && isset($result[$id]['cars'][$carId]) && !isset($result[$id]['cars'][$carId]['insurance'][$insId])) {
        $insurance = array(
            'id'         => $row['INSURANCE_ID'],
            'start_date' => $row['START_DATE'],
            'end_date'   => $row['END_DATE'],
            'price'      => $row['PRICE']
        );
        $result[$id]['cars'][$carId]['insurance'][$insId] = $insurance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the values (clients, cars, insurance) as arrays instead of objects and index the arrays numerically?

Comment: @Norbert actually there are also an arrays in my example and yes it is not hard to make them numerical autoindexed rather than use own keys. You should just additionally iterate over already added items of cars and insurance and check correspond id values to make sure the item that you want to add is not yet exists.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to write out all of the necessary fields for you, but it really does come down to just a single fetch loop and some `if()` logic to build the sub-arrays:

```
$info = array()
while($row = fetch from db) {
    if(!isset($info[$row['userID']]) {
         $info[$row['userID']] = array(
              'first_name' => $row['first_name'],
              ...
              'cars' => array()
         );
    }
    if (!isset($info[$row['userID']]['cars'][$row['carID']]) {
         etc...
    }
}
```

For every sub-array you put in, you just need another `if()` test to initialize that subarray, then populate it from the `$row` you've fetched.

You'll naturally build up your structure as you iterate the rows.